# How to increase Indy idFTP buffer?

Tags: delphi-xe, indy

The OnFtpWork event fires really often for idFTP. IF it writes that often to disk then it will be a waste of time. Is there a way to increase the buffer so it will write to disk not often than once per second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `TIdFTP.IOHandler.SendBufferSize` and `TIdFTP.IOHandler.RecvBufferSize` properties before performing a transfer.  They will be copied to the `IOHandler` used for the transfer connection.

Or you can use the `TIdFTP.OnDataChannelCreate` event to set the `ADataChannel.IOHandler.SendBufferSize` and `ADataChannel.IOHandler.RecvBufferSize` properties.

Or you can implement a `TFileStream` derived class that uses buffered file I/O internally, then you don't have to mess with `TIdFTP`'s buffers.